# The url works in localhost but not in server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I use `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);` to forward from servlet to jsp, but this does not work in server. I used `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/message.jsp");` but then jsp does not show the message which I send from servlet. How to solve it?

Comment: Why `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher()` and not `request.getRequestDispatcher()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a sendRedirect instead of a forward, you will create a new request, which will cause your request attributes to be gone. Some frameworks use a 'flash' scope (essentially 2 times a request) instead of the request or session scope to handle this. In your case, however, there is no flash scope since you are using plain Servlets/JSP.

Instead,  you can do something like:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext().getContext(request.getContextPath());
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Which should forward the current request to the message.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

you can do by this way

```
 request.setAttribute("PARAM1", "VALUE1");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("message.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

and in your `Message.jsp` retrieve your set value.

```
request.getAttribute("PARAM1");
```